# How prevent dissapear Emoji symbols in UISegmentedControl

Tags: cocoa-touch, uisegmentedcontrol, emoji

If I want to put emoji in my segmented control I probably want to get image on first row but get 2nd and 3rd.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Just put `@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}` as text attribute for UIControlStateSelected state

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSDictionary *dict = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};


    [self.segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:dict forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}

@end
```